# Cannot implicitly convert from dialog result to bool

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to reproduce code from wpf to winforms (this code works inside wpf)

```
public static bool? ShowSettingsDialogFor(ICustomCustomer)
{
   if (cust is BasicCustomer)
   {
      return (new BCustomerSettingsDialog()).ShowDialog();
   }
}
```

I'm getting compile error message

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' to
>   'bool?'

Comment: Why do you want return a `DialogResult`? Error message clearly says: _You define boolean as a return value of this method but you are returning a instance of DialogResult. What the hell?_ Clearly you might need to use `DialogResult` enumeration for returning a boolean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change that to

```
return (new BCustomerSettingsDialog()).ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK;
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that, in Windows Forms, the [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method returns a [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) enumeration value. The range of possible values depends on which buttons you have available, and their `bool?` conversion may depend on what they imply within your application. Below is some generic logic to handle a few cases:

```
public static bool? ShowSettingsDialogFor(ICustomCustomer)
{
   if (cust is BasicCustomer)
   {
      DialogResult result = (new BCustomerSettingsDialog()).ShowDialog();

      switch (result)
      {
          case DialogResult.OK:
          case DialogResult.Yes:
              return true;

          case DialogResult.No:
          case DialogResult.Abort:
              return false;

          case DialogResult.None:
          case DialogResult.Cancel:
              return null;

          default:
              throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected dialog result.")
      }
   }
}
```